# How to use new android Scoped Storage in kivy app

Tags: python, kivy

I have a kivy android app that can edit images and save them to it's own directory. Since android 10 (from API level 29) android says we are no longer allowed to directly access external storages.
I read lot of documentations about Scoped storage but all of them in java and kotlin which i am not familiar with.

Can someone explain and provide example code how to use Scoped storage within a kivy app. Since i am a beginner i have no idea should i use Pyjnius, Plyer or something else.

Comment: If you could point me to those Java docs, I might be able to help.

Comment: I created [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67129296/storage-access-framework-in-python) similar post.